# flutter google firebase sign in requires every time the user start the app

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter, google-signin

i am trying to use firebase authentication for google sign in but my sign process requires every time while starting the app.what to do if user already logged in once then navigate to the home page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'sign_in.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Login_page extends StatelessWidget {


Future<bool> _login_user()async{
final sign_in=await Sign_in_google.sign_with_google();
if(sign_in!=null){
  return true;
}
else{
  return false;
}
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text('Food Reviewer'),
  ),
  body: new Center(
    child: new RaisedButton(
      child: new Text('google sign in'),
      onPressed: ()async{
        bool result=await _login_user();
        result ? Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("home_page"):
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
          content: new Text('wrong email'),
        ));

      },
    ),
  ),
);
 }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use an `AuthStateListener` to detect the login state before calling `_login_user `. See [`addStateDidChangeListener` in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user).

Comment: thanks for your reply..can you give me some reference article.it will be great for me.